# Why can I not use type variables in this instance declaration?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `TypeApplications` to disambiguate between which instance of a type class I am calling. Unfortunately, it seems that an instance declaration's type parameters cannot be used in the instance body. Specifically, in this toy example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class Foo a where
    foo :: String

instance Foo () where
    foo = "()"

instance Foo Int where
    foo = "Int"

class Bar b where
    bar :: String

instance Foo a => Bar a where
    bar = foo @a
```

will error with `Not in scope: type variable 'a'` at the last line. If I remove the type application, instead the error `Could not deduce (Foo a0) from the context Foo a` is given, which is reasonable, ass `foo` by itself  is ambiguous.

Is there some way for me to access the type parameter, or otherwise coerce the compiler into recognising this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A type variable can be used in an instance declaration, but only if it's *scoped*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax      #-}

class Foo a where foo :: String

class Bar b where bar :: String

instance ∀ a . Foo a => Bar a where
  bar = foo @a
```

As always, `∀` can also be written `forall` if you prefer ASCII.

Comment: The `∀ a .` is optional above -- `a` is in scope anyway according to GHC. Perhaps it's a good style to include it anyway, as we have to do elsewhere to bring `a` in scope. (To be honest, I never used that, and did not know that one can use `forall` in instances)